# What does "key (gt_num_keys)" mean in tiff image(gtiff)

Tags: image, graphics, tiff, geotiff

I'm currently working on a imageblending project, there are some part of the sample code I'm having trouble understanding.

In the part about geotiff/tiff, what is the meaning of "key  (gt_num_keys)" in a tiff image(gtiff)?

Here's the code:

```
int numkeys1 = gtif1->gt_num_keys;

gtif2->gt_methods.get(tif2, GTIFF_PIXELSCALE, &pscount2, &psdata2 );
```